# Are custom preconditions valid for a move assignment operator?

Tags: c++, move-semantics

Is it valid to place custom preconditions on the state of the move target in a move assignment operator? In particular, would it be valid to only allow moving to an object that has not been fully initialized before?

Consider:

```
struct Foo {
private:
  std::unique_ptr<int> value;

public:
  Foo(std::unique_ptr<int> value) : value{std::move(value)} {}

  Foo(Foo&&) noexcept = default;
  Foo &operator =(Foo&& other) noexcept {
    assert(!value);
    value = std::move(other.value);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

I wonder, e.g., if this class can be used with a container, without hitting the assertion. E.g. if you do:

```
    std::vector<Foo> foo;
    foo.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(42));
    foo.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(17));
    Foo removed = std::move(foo[0]);
    foo.erase(foo.begin());
```

Were this guaranteed to work with the class, or is this relying on implementation details of `std::vector`?

Comment: `Foo removed = std::move(foo[0]);` is a *construction* of `removed`, not assignment. Therefore the (defaulted) "move" or r-value constructor `Foo(Foo&&)` will be invoked.

Comment: Your move assignment operator can do anything that's defined behavior in C++. As far as whether "this guaranteed to work with the class", it's not clear what's stopping you from trying to compile and run the code yourself, and seeing if it works.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik " and seeing if it works. " That it works in the given snipped did not guarantee anything. My understanding is: "Is it always safe to not move in a move assignment operator or move constructor". But the answer is : Yes!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sure. It's just there to allow a typical implementation of `erase` to not hit the assertion.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik My question is not if this program works with a specific C++ compiler and standard library implementation (it works with my clang/libc++ version), but if the C++ standard requires this to work. And the using code is just an example.

Comment: @Klaus I don't understand your comment. What do you mean by "safe to not move". The Foo move assignment operator in the example does move if it returns.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it valid to place custom preconditions on the state of the move target in a move assignment operator?

Yes, but...

> In particular, would it be valid to only allow moving to an object that has not been fully initialized before?

Sure, but...

> Consider:

No problem so far, but...

```
std::vector<Foo> foo;
// ...
```

You can do anything you want with your class until you use it with std-code (or somebody else's code) which puts requirements on your type.

For example the standard says [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/sequence.reqmts#tab:container.seq.req) about `vector::erase`:

> For `vector` and `deque`, `T` is *Cpp17MoveAssignable*.

And *Cpp17MoveAssignable* is defined [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/utility.arg.requirements#tab:cpp17.moveassignable).

```
t = rv
```

> `rv`’s state is unspecified. [*Note*: `rv` must still meet the requirements of the library component that is using it, whether or not `t` and `rv` refer to the same object. The operations listed in those requirements must work as specified whether `rv` has been moved from or not. —*end note*]

`Foo` doesn't fully meet the Cpp17MoveAssignable requirements.  And that's fine as long as you don't expect `Foo` to work with code that *requires* Cpp17MoveAssignable.

*Disclaimer:*  A future standard *might* relax the requirements on `vector::erase` so as to allow `Foo`.  But that is not the case today.

Note that `std::remove_if` *also* requires *Cpp17MoveAssignable*:

http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.remove#2

And this slight modification of your program actually will assert:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
private:
  std::unique_ptr<int> value;

public:
  Foo(std::unique_ptr<int> value) : value{std::move(value)} {}

  Foo(Foo&&) noexcept = default;
  Foo &operator =(Foo&& other) noexcept {
    assert(!value);
    value = std::move(other.value);
    return *this;
  }

  bool operator==(int i) const {return *value == i;}
};

int
main()
{
    std::vector<Foo> foo;
    foo.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(1));
    foo.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(2));
    foo.push_back(std::make_unique<int>(3));
    std::remove_if(foo.begin(), foo.end(),
        [](auto const& f) {return f == 1;});
}
```

Comment: I don't think Foo violates anything explicitly stated in the Cpp17MoveAssignable requirements. Foo's move assignment operator places constraints on the `t` the operation is called, and my question is if this is valid. What you are quoting is just that Cpp17MoveAssignable doesn't require it to provide any other post-conditions for `rv`. My

Comment: @Simon there are no preconditions on `t`, so `t = rv` must be valid for all possible `t`s

Comment: @Caleth Yes, probably that's it. As I said before, it's not mentioned explicitly, but implicitly it is requiring that for all possible t, as you say. So the answer to my original question is simply: no.